# HTTP client using socket, seems to work for google only

Tags: python, http

I wrote some code to do a get request in pyhton using socket. When I do the request for google.com. it works fine, but any other uri gives 400 bad request, any ideas on why this is?

```
def send(http_command, uri, client):
    FORMAT = 'utf-8'
    msg = http_command+" / HTTP/1.1\r\n"+uri+'\r\n\r\n'
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    client.send(message)
```

Comment: http/1.1 request must contain `host` header, you send just uri instead

Comment: I changed the `msg = http_command+" / HTTP/1.1\r\n"+uri+'\r\n\r\n'`  to `msg = http_command+" / HTTP/1.1\r\n"+'host:'+uri+'\r\n\r\n' ` now it works, thanks!